# adding gradient to UIView in drawRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, graphics, gradient

I am trying to add a CAGradientLayer in my drawRect, the code is the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CAGradientLayer *gradientOverlay = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGColorRef grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:37/255.f green:37/255.f 
                                            blue:37/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor; 
    CGColorRef blueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 
                                            blue:219.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    gradientOverlay.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id) grayColor,
                              (id) grayColor,
                              (id) blueColor,
                              nil];
    gradientOverlay.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1],
                                 nil];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    gradientOverlay.startPoint = startPoint;
    gradientOverlay.frame = self.bounds;
    gradientOverlay.endPoint = endPoint;

    self.layer.mask = gradientOverlay;

}
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: No. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Probably because your setting the gradient as the mask.  The mask layer is used to clip visibility in custom ways, such as rounding corners... It will not display whatever layer it is set to. EDIT: Try adding it as a sublayer instead.

Comment: It seems like you're copying and pasting code without really understanding it. That's not a recipe for success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `CAGradientLayer` as a sublayer of your `self.layer`.

**Note**: If you're doing it in the `drawRect:` method make sure you're not adding a new `CAGradientLayer` every time `drawRect:` is called.

**UPDATE** (regarding the comment):
Here's the code for what you're asking:

```
    //Create a layer that holds your background image and add it as sublayer of your self.layer
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.frame = self.layer.frame;
    layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"].CGImage;
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];

//Create your CAGradientLayer
    CAGradientLayer *gradientOverlay = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGColorRef grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:37/255.f green:37/255.f 
                                            blue:37/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor; 
    CGColorRef blueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 
                                            blue:219.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    gradientOverlay.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id) grayColor,
                              (id) grayColor,
                              (id) blueColor,
                              nil];
    gradientOverlay.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1],
                                 nil];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    gradientOverlay.startPoint = startPoint;
    gradientOverlay.frame = self.layer.frame;
    gradientOverlay.endPoint = endPoint;
//set its opacity from 0 ~ 1
    gradientOverlay.opacity = 0.6f;
//add it as sublayer of self.layer (it will be over the layer with the background image
    [self.layer addSublayer:gradientOverlay];
```

**Note**: You don't have to do this in `drawRect:` method. Create your layer hierarchy in the `init` method for example, if you need to change the geometry of some views/layers override the `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: hmm.. is it possible to have the gradient to have a transparency? I have an image drawn using CG and when I do a addsublayer I can't see the image drawn behind it

Comment: also one more minor thing, I have specified the gradient to have 3 different colors.. however I am only seeing gray color all towards the gradient

Comment: You might need to play around with the values, especially when there is a background image. Try it first on white background, then with the image behind...

Comment: I've tried just with no image behind it and all I see is just gray

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, the `startPoint` and the `endPoint` of `CAGradientLayer` are in the unit coordinate system - their values are between `0` and `1` as the `startPoint` default is {0.5, 0.0}  and the `endPoint` is {0.5, 1.0}

Answer (score 2):

How about trying this instead of overriding drawRect?

```
+ (void) applyGradient:(NSArray *)cgColors toView:(UIView *)view {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = cgColors;
    for(CALayer *layer in view.layer.sublayers) {
        if([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]]) return;
    }
    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: You should check for the CAGradientLayer before creating it. This half defeats the purpose.

Comment: +1 This was the solution that worked for me. Simple and effective, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should only override `drawRect:` when you will be drawing your view using CoreGraphics.

A better place to put your code would be in `init` if you're creating this view in code, or `awakeFromNib` if you're placing this view in a .xib