# Adding a CAGradientLayer to drawn UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, bar-chart, drawrect, cagradientlayer

I wanted to draw a 3d bar graph, I've searched the web and find [this](http://codereply.com/answer/6kx07p/draw-3d-bar-graph-ios.html) website and this piece of code:

```
- (void)drawBarOfHeight:(CGFloat)bheight width:(CGFloat)bwidth colour:(UIColor *)acolor atOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{
    CGPoint correctedOrigin = origin;
    //draw the front face , its a plain rectangle - semi dark
    [[self tintOfColor:acolor tint:0.8] set];
    UIBezierPath *face1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(correctedOrigin.x, correctedOrigin.y - bheight, bwidth, bheight)];
    [face1 fill];
    //basic trig
    CGFloat PI = 3.141;
    CGFloat theta = 30;
    CGFloat section = bwidth * 0.6; //bit of jiggling otherwise it looks crappy
    CGFloat yoffset = section * sinf(theta * PI/180); //needs radians
    CGFloat xoffset = section * cosf(theta * PI/180);
    //draw the side face , its a trapezoid set at theta -
    UIBezierPath *face2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [face2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth, correctedOrigin.y)];
    [face2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth, correctedOrigin.y - bheight)];
    [face2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth + xoffset, correctedOrigin.y - bheight - yoffset)];
    [face2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth + xoffset, correctedOrigin.y - yoffset)];
    //darkest shade
    [[self tintOfColor:acolor tint:0.6] set];
    [face2 fill];
    //draw the other face , its another trapezoid
    UIBezierPath *face3 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [face3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x , correctedOrigin.y - bheight )];
    [face3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + xoffset, correctedOrigin.y - bheight - yoffset)];
    [face3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth + xoffset, correctedOrigin.y - bheight - yoffset)];
    [face3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(correctedOrigin.x + bwidth, correctedOrigin.y - bheight)];
    //base shade of colour
    [[self tintOfColor:acolor tint:1.0] set];
    [face3 fill];
}

- (CAGradientLayer *)gradientLayerWithTopColor:(UIColor*)topColor bottomColor:(UIColor*)bottomColor
{
    NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
    NSArray *gradientLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0], nil];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors;
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations;

    return gradientLayer;
}

- (UIColor *)tintOfColor:(UIColor *)acolor tint:(CGFloat)tint
{
    //tint > 1.0 lightens
    //tint < 1.0 darkens
    CGFloat red = 1.0;
    CGFloat green = 1.0;
    CGFloat blue = 1.0;
    CGFloat alpha = 1.0;
    if ([acolor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha])
    {
        red *= tint;
        green *= tint;
        blue *= tint;
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    }
    return acolor; //in case the call failed , return original
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //as an example
    [self drawBarOfHeight:250 width:40 colour:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2] atOrigin:CGPointMake(100, 500)];
    [self drawBarOfHeight:30 width:40 colour:[UIColor yellowColor] atOrigin:CGPointMake(100, 500)];
}
```

Now I want to add a gradient to one of the graphs so I've added this method:

```
- (CAGradientLayer *)gradientLayerWithTopColor:(UIColor*)topColor bottomColor:(UIColor*)bottomColor
```

But can't figure out how can I migrate it with the code i'm using on top?

Thanks in advance

---

Update: when drawing the second `UIBezierPath` (face2) this is what I get:

[image]

How can I avoid that? and draw the gradient in the exact tilt and exact frame of the `UIBezierPath`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904160/adding-gradient-to-uiview-in-drawrect

Comment: My problem is not with the first UIBezierPath (face1) is with the second UIBezierPath (face2) that is drawn with points.. check my answer for update..

Comment: Use paint code, frame your view give it rectangle coordinates, and you are done. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95828b4dd7e54dab9dfc